# Power series of bounded linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a Banach space $X$ and a bounded linear map $T:X\rightarrow X$ we define $$e^T = I + \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{T^n}{n!}$$
Show that if $e^T$ is compact then dim $X<\infty$.

I have showed before that $e^T$ converges in operator norm and obviously it commutes with $T$. Hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for which $T$ is $e^T$ invertible? (Think about the case $X=\mathbb{R}$).

[Invertibility of compact operators in infinite-dimensional Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/invertibility-of-compact-operators-in-infinite-dimensions) might help.