# 1-separated sequences of unit vectors in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$, I would like to construct a sequence of linearly independent unit vectors such that $\|u_k-u_l\|\geqslant 1$ whenever $k\neq l$. Any ideas on how to realize this?

Comment: Would you settle for $\|u_k-u_l\|\geq 1-\varepsilon$? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/fitting-an-infinite-collection-of-balls-in-an-infinite-dimensional-unit-ball  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163500/an-application-of-riesz-lemma

Comment: Elton and Odell proved that in an infinite dimensional normed linear space, there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence  $(x_n)$ of unit vectors that satisfy $\Vert x_n-x_m\Vert\ge 1+\epsilon$ for $n\ne m$. This (difficult result)  can be found in the last chapter of Joseph Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.  In chapter one of the same book, it is shown, fairly simply (and attributed to Cliff Kottman),  that in an infinite dimensional normed space,  one can find a sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $\Vert x_n-x_m\Vert>1$ for $n\ne m$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Neat!  It improves on Riesz's lemma, from which you can't generally get better than $1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: The original paper of Kottman is: Kottman, C. A. 1975. Subsets of the unit ball that are separated by more than one. *Studia math*., 53, 15-27.  A simpler proof of the result is in Diestel's book, and is attributed to Tom Starbird.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/296318/

Answer (score 3):

It can be done fairly easily in any infinite dimensional normed space $X$. For a proof, see  [Lemma 1.4.22](http://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA33&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Robert E. Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*.