# An infinite subset of the closed unit ball whose elements are more than distance 1 apart

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be any infinite dimensional normed space. Is it always possible to find $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$ be a countbly infinite subset of the closed unit ball, such that $||x_i-x_j||>1$ whenever $i\neq j$?

So far I have tried a few sequence spaces and $C[0,1]$ under various norms and I can find such a subset. I have not proved it or found an counterexample.

Comment: If you only demand that $\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert>\epsilon$, for a fixed $0<\epsilon<1$, then this is a consequence of Riesz's lemma.  Cliff Kottman has shown that the answer to your question is "yes". This can be found in the notes to chapter one of Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.  See, also, the comments to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215100/constructing-a-sequence-in-banach-space) post.

Comment: This was also shared in David Mitra's comments at [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/215100/) (but that one was not a duplicate of this one because it only asked for $\geq 1$).  @David: Would you mind posting an answer to one or both of these questions?

Comment: @DavidMitra I am reading Kottman's paper but I think there seems to be a bug in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only demand that $\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert>\epsilon$, for a fixed $0<\epsilon<1$, then this is a consequence of Riesz's lemma.

Cliff Kottman has shown that the answer to your question is "yes". This result can be found in the notes to Chapter one of Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.

For completeness,
here is the argument given in Diestel (which is attributed to Bob Huff and Tom Starbird):

**Theorem:**. If $X$ is an infinite dimensional normed linear space, then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of norm-one elements of $X$ for which $\Vert x_n-x_m\Vert>1$ whenever $n\ne m$.

*Proof:* We define the required sequence $(x_n)$ by induction.

To start, choose $x_1\in X$ of norm one and $x_1^*\in X^*$ such that $\Vert x_1^*\Vert= x_1^* x_1=1$.

Now suppose appropriate linearly independent norm-one vectors $x_1^*,\ldots x_k^*$ from $X^*$ and norm-one elements $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ of $X$ have been chosen.

Choose $y\in X$ so that 
$$\tag{1}x_i^* y<0\text{ for each }i=1,\ldots k,$$ and let $x$ be a non-zero vector such that
$$\tag{2}x\in\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^k \text{ker}\ x_i^*.$$ Choose $K$ so that $$\tag{3}\Vert y\Vert <\Vert y+Kx\Vert.$$

Using $(2)$, one easily verifies that for a non-trivial linear combination $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\alpha_i x_i^*$ of the $x_i^*$, we have:
$$
\biggl|\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i x_i^*(y+Kx)\biggr|\le
\biggl\Vert\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i x_i^* \biggr\Vert  \Vert y\Vert;
$$
whence by $(3)$ 
$$\tag{4}
\biggl|\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i x_i^*(y+Kx)\biggr|<\Vert y+Kx\Vert.
$$

Now define
$$
x_{k+1} ={y+Kx\over\Vert y+Kx\Vert}.
$$
Using Hahn-Banach, choose $x_{k+1}^*$ to be a norm one element of $X^*$ satisfying $$ x^*_{k+1} x_{k+1}=1.$$

Then by $(4)$ it follows that $x_{k+1}^*$ is not a linear combination of $x_1^*,\ldots, x_k^*$ (if $x_{k+1}^*=\sum_{i=i}^k\alpha_i x_i^*$, evaluate both sides at $x_{k+1}$).

Finally, we have, for $1\le i\le k$
$$
\Vert x_{k+1}-x_i\Vert\ge |x_i^*( x_{k+1}-x_i)|=|x_i^* x_{k+1} - x_i^* x_i|.
$$
Now, $x_i^* x_i=1$. Also, $x_i^* x_{k+1}<0$ by the definition of $x_{k+1}$, $(1)$ and $(2)$.  Thus $\Vert x_{k+1}-x_i\Vert >1$, as desired.

---

See, also, the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215100/constructing-a-sequence-in-banach-space) post. A result due to John Elton and Edward Odell shows that one can actually find an $\epsilon>0$ (which depends on the space) and a sequence of norm one elements $(x_n)$ such that $\Vert x_n-x_m\Vert\ge1+\epsilon$ whenever $n\ne m$!

Comment: I must confess, I do not see how to find the $y$ in $(1)$. I'm probably overlooking something simple here...

Comment: Since the $x_{i}^\ast$ are linearly independent, the map $X \to \mathbb{R}^k, x \mapsto (x_1^\ast(x),\dots, x_k^\ast(x))$ is onto, otherwise you have a non-trivial linear relation between them.