# Constructing a special kind of sequence in an infinite dimensional normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Show that every infinite dimensional normed linear space contains a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ $\forall$ and $\|x_m-x_n\| \geq 1$ for all $m ,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $m \neq n$.

I tried to show it by using the fact that every infinite dimensional norm linear space admits a linear discontinuous functional. But I am stuck and the idea is leading nowhere. Also if that was something less than 1 we could use 
Riesz's Lemma but here it doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I am recalling that this involves showing that every closed subspace in a Banach space has a vector in its complement that is "far away" from it, and I think I saw this in Ch 5 of Gilbarg-Trudinger's book on Elliptic PDEs?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215100/1-separated-sequences-of-unit-vectors-in-banach-spaces) (and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296318/an-infinite-subset-of-the-closed-unit-ball-whose-elements-are-more-than-distance)).

Comment: Thank you David I got it!!!!