# Infinite number of disjoint closed ball in unit ball

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Currently I'm trying to prove that for :
An infinite linear space X with norm, there exist an infinite family of disjoint balls $B(x_{n},\epsilon)$ that are in $B(0,1)$ .

I've already checked this link

[Fitting an infinite collection of balls in an infinite dimensional unit ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/fitting-an-infinite-collection-of-balls-in-an-infinite-dimensional-unit-ball)

but trully I can't understand the last sentence, why we changed the centers and how we are sure that these balls are disjoint ??And also this proof can work for any $\epsilon$??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If U is open and not empty, then there is some r > 0, x in U
with B(x,r) subset U.  Thus K = closure B(x,r/2) subset U.
U - K is open and not empty.

Use that to construct a series of pairwise disjoint closed sets
inside of U.

Answer (score 0):

In the proof in the link there was no changing of centers. Open balls and centers are not mentioned until the last sentence. Before that, there was just a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of unit vectors. And of course unit vectors do not belong to $B(0,1).$

Let $0<\epsilon <1.$ Let $S_n$ be the linear span of $\{x_j:1\leq j\leq n\}.$ Let the distance $d(x_{n+1},S_n)$, from $x_{n+1}$ to $S_n,$ be greater than $1-\epsilon.$

Let $r=\frac {1}{3}(1-\epsilon).$ Let  For $m<n,$ we have  $$\|\frac {2}{3}x_n - 
 \frac {2}{3}x_m\|\geq \frac {2}{3}d(x_n,S_{n-1})>\frac {2}{3}(1-\epsilon)=2r.$$  $$\text {Therefore }\quad B(\frac {2}{3}x_m,r)\cap B(\frac {2}{3}x_n,r)=\phi.$$  And each $B(\frac {2}{3}x_m,r)\subset B(0,1)$ because  $\|\frac {2}{3}x_m\|+r=\frac {2}{3}+r=1-\frac {1}{3}\epsilon <1.$

Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, $r$ can be arbitrarily close to $1/3.$

I don't know whether $r<1/3$ is the best possible result in general. It seems so, if we restrict ourselves to this type of construction.

Because, with $0<K<1,$ when $m\ne n$: To ensure that $B(Kx_m,r)\cap B(Kx_n,r)=\phi$  we must have  $r\leq \|Kx_m-Kx_n\|/2,$ and  to ensure that $B(Kx_n,r)\subset B(0,1)$  we must have $r\leq 1-K.$ Together these imply $3r\leq \|Kx_m-Kx_n\|+1-K,$ so if the best upper bound that we have for  $\|Kx_m-Kx_n\|$ is less than $K$, then  $r < 1/3.$